# Javascript to pull out data-page from <li class="c-pagination__item" data-page="2">

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this is similar to another post and I used that answer, however, because the class has c-pagination it is causing an error.

```js
const pagesList = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName("c-pagination__item"), // collection to create the array from
 c-pagination__item => c-pagination__item.getAttribute('data-page') // mapper function
);
console.log(pagesList);
```

I have tried () and that didn't help.  How can I get the c-pagination_item to be seen as one thing?  The error I am getting is: Exception: SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)

Answer (score 1):

The argument `c-pagination__item` in the mapper function is not a valid [JS identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier). `-` is not a valid character.

try to replace it with `_`

```
const pagesList = Array.from(
   document.getElementsByClassName("c-pagination__item"), // collection to create the array from
   c_pagination__item => c_pagination__item.getAttribute('data-page') // mapper function
);
console.log(pagesList);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that it wouldn't stay recognized from the getElements line to the next one, but I guess it isn't an issue after all.